# unset multidimensional array value, reorder, and return in Php?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

My question is similar to this one-

[PHP | Remove element from array with reordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172937/php-remove-element-from-array-with-reordering)

...except that when I return the ordered array, I want the keys to start from 1. My array, however, is multidimensional. From reading the comments in the PhP manual about the array_values function, I understand that something weird happens with the keys (Carsten Milkau writes: 'Note that in a multidimensional array, each element may be identified by a *sequence* of keys, i.e. the keys that lead towards that element.')

This is baffling me, as it seems I can no longer simply use a foreach loop to iterate through the array and add 1 to the key value each time. I'd greatly appreciate some help with this, otherwise I'm going to have to implement some seriously ugly and verbose work-around... here is my code:

```
// $orderedData contains, for example, $orderedData['image_data'][1]['code'] and $orderedData['image_data'][1]['caption']  etc.

function remove_image($orderedData, $imageNo){
    unset($orderedData['image_data'][$imageNo]);
    $newArray = array_values($orderedData['image_data']);

    // Now I need to shift the keys of $newArray so that $newArray[0]['code'] becomes $newArray[1]['code'] etc.

}
```

Comment: When I started programming I hated that count starts from 0 not from 1, with time I get used to it and found some common sense in it. Also there are many benefits of starting count from 0 even in storing order of records in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$i = 0;
$new_array = array();
foreach($orderedData as $value)
{
    ++$i;
    $new_array[$i] = $value;
}
```

Comment: Ah, a mucher simpler approach, don't know why I didn't think of that! I've actually changed the 3rd line to foreach($orderedData['image_data'] as $value) , as it was only those values that I was after, but this works perfectly! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should suit your purpose, add to the bottom of that function:

```
array_unshift($newArray, array());
unset($newArray[0]);
```

Comment: I like this, but seems a bit of a hack to add something then remove it, so I'm going with styu's answer above, but thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172937/php-remove-element-from-array-with-reordering/47865489#47865489